# Testing code in at_exit with Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, atexit

I have a ruby app that needs to, among other things, close some databases at exit. For this I use the  `at_exit` method. The code looks something like this:

```
at_exit do
    close_databases
    #more code
    say_goodbye
end

require "gems"
#...code
```

I have specs for all the method calls used, but I would like to be able to test the code inside the `at_exit` method. Is it possible? If so, how can I write the specs for that?

Comment: You say you want to test the code inside the at_exit method, and you say that you have already tested all the method calls used.  This should mean that `close_databases` and `say_goodbye` are already tested, and as they are in the code in the `at_exit` block, it seems you have already tested the code inside the at_exit block.  Done!  If this is not the case, Ruby is your friend.  Rewrite the at_exit method to take a block and test it.

Comment: Good point, just realised myself. However, I won't get 100% coverage :p Would love to get that green line somehow. But yeah `at_exit do ; do_at_exit(); end ; def do_at_exit ; some_code ; end` would probably do the trick.

Comment: Yep, I came to the same conclusion. It is easy to test `close_databases` and `say_goodbye`, but I still want to make sure they get called when the app exits.